# sql sum of results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am pulling everything from a database table and displaying specific data in php.

So far all my code is working, I'm able to display in php everything but I'm trying to make another php file to only display specific data. For example I want it to find everything in the `movieview` table and only display all row data that has a `playcount` of equal or greater than 1 and to display it by title ascending which is

```
 $SQL = "select * from movieview WHERE playCount>=1 Order By c00 Asc";
 $result = mysql_query($SQL);

 while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

 $imdb = $db_field['c09'];
 $run = $db_field['c11'];
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run); 
 $sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

Now I want to `echo $sum;` to add up all values of `c11` from all the results that matched `playcount` of equal or greater then 1. The reason I haven't tried the SQL `sum` is because below I am displaying more columns which i believe is the reason for `select *`

**edit:** if i do the following:

```
 $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
 $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

 if ($db_found) {

 $SQL = "select * from movieview WHERE playCount>=1 Order By c00 Asc";
 $result = mysql_query($SQL);

 while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

 $imdb = $db_field['c09'];
 $run = $db_field['c11'];

 echo $run;
```

it does display the times of all the items with a playcount of 1 or more which is good. now im just just wish to make a total of all those `$run` values in 1 sum and echo that. i also have extra tables that are called in the php file, just a note, like mid, idb, and c00.

now, if i do :
     $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
     $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

```
 if ($db_found) {

 $SQL = "select SUM(c11) AS totalrun from movieview WHERE playCount>=1 Order By c00 Asc ";
 $result = mysql_query($SQL);

 while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

 $imdb = $db_field['c09'];
 $run = $db_field['totalrun'];
```

i am able to echo the totals, yey!, but i cant call on the other columns listed above.

Comment: table definition, sample input and desired output

Comment: What about SUM(c11)?

Comment: @MawiaHL how would i display an echo in php of it the SUM(c11)?

Comment: i edited the question to show the sum() which works but i cant use any other column now...

Answer (score 1):

If i understood well your question, you can do this:

```
$counter=0;

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

 $imdb = $db_field['c09'];
 $run = $db_field['c11'];
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run); 
 $sum = $row['value_sum'];
 $counter .= $row['c11'];
}



echo $counter;
```

Comment: thanks but for some reason it echos 0 values for each item

Answer (score 1):

If you just keep on adding the total run it should work , If I have understood it correctly

```
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

 $SQL = "select * from movieview WHERE playCount>=1 Order By c00 Asc"; 
 $result = mysql_query($SQL);
 $run=0;
 while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

 $imdb = $db_field['c09'];
 $run = $run + $db_field['c11'];
 }
echo $run;
```

Comment: throws out a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE in line 19 which is while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) { edit; nevermind corrected $run=0; in your code. it works, now im seeing results BUT i am now seeing all the runs values not just the single total.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to do it by creating another sql query. not sure how proper it is but it works. the only thing missing is that each result is only counted 1x so if a playcount of 2 or more is only seen as 1. will work on that later unless you can reply with a fix :D

```
 while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {

 $run = $db_field['SUM(c11)'];
```